# how can I estimate row count in mysql search query?

Tags: mysql, sql

When you search in gmail for a word gmail say:
1–20 of about 98

that 98 is an estimated value How can I do this with mysql in our search?

I don't want to use `COUNT` function or `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` because I have a 1M row and using a `fulltext` search.
I want to estimate not count!

Comment: what have you tried so far?? any query that you want to share. or any error you are getting??

Comment: Have you tried `select count(*) from ... where ...`

Comment: sorry I want to estimate the row for better performance

Comment: "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil" – Donald Knuth. If you've got an index on your table a `COUNT()` should be pretty quick

Comment: @Bojangles fulltext is a kind of index and I used it, but you see that google use of estimation instead of counting all row

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `count` or `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` doesn't help you have some options :

1. Ask information_schema tables

```sql
select  table_rows
from    information_schema.tables
where   table_schema = 'database_name'
  and   table_name = 'table_name' ;
```

Estimate but very performant.

2. Externalize `counter` value in an other table and update it during insert/delete statement (more performant and accurate but add overhead on write statements)
3. Cache counter in your application (we can imagine having a kind of background worker that will get "updated"  value each 30 min and update the value in the cache) The service will always use the cache value

Solution 1 and 3 is about `estimates` but don't forget the tricky part (count with filtered columns.. so with `where` clause)... Solution 1 doesn't help anymore, Solution 2 and 3 will required to maintain multiple `counter` based on some "static filtering" like `count() where sexe='M'` ...

Finally with random filter values.. you're stuck.. and you'll need to go with the `count` option on target table with optimal indexing (or maybe trying by indexing data in a full-text search like Elastic search)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the size of the table (size on disk).

Try to make a query like this:

```
SELECT DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME='...';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html

Comment: I know that it's possible for estimating the all row of table.
you say that it's useable for search result? (not all row)

Comment: No, I didn't know that you need a WHERE clause. Maybe there is another method for what you want.